# Application Freezes When Sorting 1000+ numbers

Tags: c#, file, sorting

I made a program that generates and sorts data but when I try generating about 1000 numbers the program freezes and wont respond. It also loads in data from a file but any big file freezes the program. Is there any way around this?

```
public void generateData(int number)
    {
        //Clear text boxes and initialize random 
        Unsorted_Box.Clear();
        Sorted_Box.Clear();
        Random random = new Random();
        dataArray = new int[number];

        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            //Generate random numbers using max and min values, ammount and store in unsorted box
            dataArray[i] = random.Next((int)Min_UpDown.Value, (int)Max_UpDown.Value);
            Unsorted_Box.Text += dataArray[i] + ", ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: There could be a problem in the code if it works fine on smaller number sizes, try checking the code with the debugger and reply if you catch any errors.

Comment: The application goes in break mode and says this "Additional information: The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x800ba8 to COM context 0x800c60 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages...

Comment: This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncheck `ContextSwitchDeadlock` under **Debug->Exceptions->Managed Debugging Assistants**.

Comment: Doing this worked but will it still work once I export the program?

Comment: it's likely that you're blocking the ui thread for >60 seconds, which is not a good idea.  Disabling that debug assistant will hide the problem.  If it's the load of data from the file that's taking the time, then consider putting it on a separate thread.

Comment: I'm still new to c# (< 1 week) so I have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If the program is freezing because it's taking a long time to process, then you could consider doing that processing on a background thread.  This will allow the rest of the program to remain responsive.

If the program is freezing because of a dead lock, then you can use the tools in visual studio to identify where this is happening.  if it's reproducible then pause in debugger and see where the problem is.

If it's neither of these 2, can you share the code you're using?

Comment: It gives me an option to keep executing the code after it freezes and if I choose that option it continues and works as it should.

Comment: Can you share the code where you are reading the file?

Comment: I shared the part where I generate the data above

Comment: Is there only one thread in your application?